# How do I check if an object has needed keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way to do? 
I am interested in lodash methods as well if there is any better approach

```js
var myObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 20,
  sex: male
}
```

I like to see whether myObj have 'name' and 'age' keys

My Approach - it works fine

```js
var myObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 20,
  sex: 'male'
}
var value;

function result() {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('name') && myObj.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
    value = true;
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
}
result();
console.log(value);
```

I can also use ('key' in  myObj)

But actually I has an object which is quiet big and need to check if they have particular keys.
Looking for any better approach

Comment: Tons of way to do it.... but if it is just a few keys, what you are doing is fine. If it is a lot of keys, object with a loop is better.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Comment: Please edit your question to be more descriptive about what you mean by "better approach". Is there something specific about what you're doing that makes you want another way?

Comment: @Naga Sai it is but not as straigh forward as this

Answer (score 2):

Put your required keys into an array:

```
let requiredKeys = ["name", "age"];
```

And then use the `Array.every` method and `Object.keys`:

```
let objectKeys = Object.keys(myObj);
let hasRequiredKeys = requiredKeys.every(k => objectKeys.includes(k));
```

Comment: `k => objectKeys.includes(k)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills - always forgetting about `.includes()`, edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of keys. Iterate the array with [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and check if each key is in the object using [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```js
const myObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 20,
  sex: 'male'
};

const hasKeys = (obj, keys) => keys.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
  
console.log(hasKeys(myObj, ['name', 'age']));

console.log(hasKeys(myObj, ['name', 'title']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *lodash*, with the *has* method

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var myObj = {
   name: 'John',
   age: 20,
   sex: male
}

var has_keys = _.has(myObj, ['name', 'age', 'sex']);
// has_keys => true
```

Comment: I have check that selby got false

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateObj (myObj) {
   var nameFound = false;
   var ageFound = false;
   for (x in myObj) {
       if (x === "name") nameFound = true;
       if (x === "age")  ageFound = true;
       if (ageFound && nameFound) return true;
   }
   return (ageFound && nameFound)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtleties to this question that may or may not be important.

Objects in Javascript have prototypes that can inherit properties from other objects. It's not clear whether `myObj` would be valid if one of the required properties is found on the prototype.

Here's an example:

```js
const parent = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 20,
    sex: 'male'
  }
 
const requiredKeys = ['name', 'age']

let valid = requiredKeys.every(key => parent.hasOwnProperty(key))

// valid becuase parent has name and age
console.log("Parent valid:", valid)

// but what about child that inherits from parent:

let child = Object.create(parent)

valid = requiredKeys.every(key => child.hasOwnProperty(key))

// not valid becuase child doesn't directly has name and age
console.log("Child Valid:", valid)

// yet those properties seem to exist because you can get them through parent's prototype:
console.log("Child name and age:", child.name, child.age)

// you can test up the protoytpe chain with …in:

valid = requiredKeys.every(key => key in child)

// now valid becuase child has name and age somewhere in the prototype chain 
console.log("Child Valid (with prototype):", valid)
```

So the question would be: which is most appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I like using lodash get for deep objects. Reason is to handle issue when any deep property is undefined or not present. Instead of errors on console and stuff use -

var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'

From - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get